# iPad 2 and iPhone 4 webviews acting differently

Tags: iphone, ipad, webview

I have an app that scans a bar code.  It then submits a link to a server and displays the info on a webview.  I'm simply calling a request with the link + the barcode result. Now the issue is my iPhone 4, iPhone 3GS all work PERFECTLY with no problem what so ever.

The iPad 2 gives me the error: this page contains the following errors: error on line 26 at column 1066: EntityRef: expecting ';'

Why would this happen on the iPad and not the iPhone?

Running 4.3.5 on the iPad, 5.0 on the iPhone, 4.3.3 on the 3GS.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I am reading in the HTML, and then displaying the HTML from that local variable. This solved the issue and a bug report was posted on Apple's site.